# Count distinct by multiple columns takes a long time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to perform count distinct in SQL server, by two fields.

I've tried two different ways. **the first one is concatenation:**

```
select count (distinct CONCAT ([UCID],[CALLSEGMENT]))
 from IVR_LINES
where UCID in (select UCID
from [EPMTest].[dbo].[IVR_LINES]
where MODULE = 'hozlap' and EVENT_NAME = 'A3' and EVENT_VALUE in ('1','2','3') and DATE> 20160911)
and EVENT_NAME = 'A6' or  EVENT_NAME = 'A7'
```

While **the second one is by using a sub-query:**

```
select COUNT(*) from(
select distinct UCID,CALLSEGMENT
 from IVR_LINES
where UCID in (select UCID
from [EPMTest].[dbo].[IVR_LINES]
where MODULE = 'hozlap' and EVENT_NAME = 'A3' and EVENT_VALUE in ('1','2','3') and DATE> 20160911)
and EVENT_NAME = 'A6' or  EVENT_NAME = 'A7'
)a
```

They take about the same running time (more than 10 seconds, probably due to the inner query itself).
 However, I would like to know - which one is more efficient? which method should I choose?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the execution plan

Comment: I'd say the first one is riskier, unless the domains of `UCID` and `CALLSEGMENT` are such as to guarantee that concatenation cannot produce false duplicates. E.g. if one row could contain `a,bc` and a second row `ab,c` then concatenating those two columns would then treat them as being equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something is wrong with your queries

first `DATE > 20160911` should give an error, 
try to replace it with `DATE > '20160911'`

second `and EVENT_NAME = 'A6' or  EVENT_NAME = 'A7'`
is **VERY** different from `and (EVENT_NAME = 'A6' or  EVENT_NAME = 'A7')`

with your syntax the queries will count many more records than (I think) expected and this could be the problem of slow execution time

talking about which is the best... they are almost the same for the optimizer

you should add some info about primary key, indexes, number of records and some example of data.

Comment: You are right. This DB isn't normalized at all, I spend a long time figuring out how to retrieve data from it. As for the date - it is not a string but a number.

Comment: glad to be of help, sorry for the date misunderstanding, I thought it was  `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 1):

Please post your execution plan to find where exactly it takes time. Meanwhile you can rewrite your query with exists clause like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT UCID
        ,CALLSEGMENT
    FROM IVR_LINES IL
    WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM [EPMTest].[dbo].[IVR_LINES]
            WHERE MODULE = 'hozlap'
                AND EVENT_NAME = 'A3'
                AND EVENT_VALUE IN (
                    '1'
                    ,'2'
                    ,'3'
                    )
                AND UCID = IL.UCID
                AND DATE > 20160911
            )
        AND EVENT_NAME IN (
            'A6'
            ,'A7'
            )
    ) A
```

Comment: This will not give the same result as the posted query because of the **and EVENT_NAME IN ('A6','A7')** replacing **and EVENT_NAME = 'A6' or  EVENT_NAME = 'A7'**. However I would think that this will give the intented result

Comment: Can you elaborate? When I run this, I get a number. What does it mean?